# What can be done to speed up vote-to-close to move the question

Tags: support, vote-to-close

There's a [question being asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076389/75642) that should be transferred to either Superuser or Serverfault. But it's getting *close* votes very very slowly.

I've changed it's title to include word: **Administration:** to make the transfer happen faster, but is still very slow.

What can be done to make it happen faster? Because otherwise the person asking the question may ask it themselves and when the question gets transferred we'll end up with two dupes.

**What can be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just flag it to Moderator's attention and request for the movement. Apart from this, I do not think you can do anything much than wait for the question to be migrated.

Comment: I've done that and [my flags were declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244653/speed-close-flags).